# How to merg Yii menu items based on the current controller being invoked (probably using CMap)?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, yii, array-merge

I have a main menu like this:

```
$main= array(
   array('label'=>'Main Menu'),
   array('label'=>'Posts', 'icon'=>'list', 'url'=>array('post/index') ),
    '--',   
   array('label'=>'Comments', 'icon'=>'comment', 'url'=>array('comment/index')),
  );
```

When in Posts controller , I build a submenu within posts e.g

```
 $submenu= array(
    array('label'=>'All Posts', 'icon'=>'list-alt', 'url'=>array("post/index")),
    array('label'=>'Create Post', 'icon'=>'plus', 'url'=>array("post/create")),
        );
```

I have function to merge both based on the

url from the $main array `'url'=>array('post/index')`

e.g

```
 list($controller,$action)=explode('/',current($link['url']));

   if($controller==$this->owner->getId()){
    $append_to=$menu_id;
    break;
    }
```

Output:

```
$main= array(
   array('label'=>'Main Menu'),
   array('label'=>'Posts', 'icon'=>'list', 'url'=>array('post/index'), 
     'items'=>array(
         array('label'=>'All Posts', 'icon'=>'list-alt', 'url'=>array("post/index")),
         array('label'=>'Create Post', 'icon'=>'plus', 'url'=>array("post/create")),
       );
     ),
    '--',   
   array('label'=>'Comments', 'icon'=>'comment', 'url'=>array('comment/index')),
  );
```

So the idea is to insert sub menu besides main menu item on run time. $menu is global, 
  while $submenu is defined in  controller.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go.

Is there a better way or Yii provides some build-in Class to do such sort of merging array conditionally ?

I checked CMap class but does not provide any such functionality .

What would you suggest to improve this piece of code ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I beleave its because there are no named keys, its not an associaciative array but rather a normal array, so **any** array merge would just append the new items.

Comment: You are right the outer-most array is non-associative. I am just curious for the best solution e.g using class , lib etc.

Comment: well, as per user experience the best solution would be to just not modify the navigation depending on the request at all, but rather to have 2 separate navigations, like site (or general navigation) and context navigation.